# Writing a shell program stdout

Tags: shell, glob, ls

Write a shell program that follows the algorithm below in order to get a
    long listing of all directories whose names end in a 3-character extension,
    and whose permissions are rwx for user (owner).

```
ALGORITHM:
1. Do the same ls command you used in question 2 above, except REDIRECT 
   the ls command's stdout to go into a file named tempFile (instead of 
   the monitor).
2. Use grep to filter the lines of tempFile so that a line is kept ONLY 
   if it corresponds to a DIRECTORY that has rwx permissions for its 
   user (owner).
3. delete (remove) tempFile
```

Im stuck on 1 i so far:

ls -ld *.??? > tempFile

Comment: Why doesn't what you have work?

Comment: Also, FIE on whoever came up with step 2.

Comment: it works but idk what i have to do for step 2

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#! /bin/bash

ls -ld * > tmp   # get a list of the permissions of all directorys in this folder and write it to the tmp file
grep "^drwx" tmp # filter the tmp files for lines beginning with drwx
rm tmp           # remove the file tmp
```